# Outcomes for multiple choice questions

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

The student is assigned the following problem:

A quiz has 7 multiple choice questions. If each question has 5 choices, how many outcomes are possible.

The answer given by the teacher is: $5^7$.

I think the answer is  only applicable to single choice question. If it is multiple choice question, each question can have $\binom{5}{2}+\binom{5}{3}+\binom{5}{4}+\binom{5}{5}=20+5+1=26$ outcomes, the total outcome should be $26^7$.

Do I miss something or is the teacher's answer wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an unfortunate linguistic quirk. A "multiple choice question", taken literally to include the possibility of more than one answer being correct, is called a multiple **response** question here at NUS; one MRQ with $k$ choices may be answered $2^k-1$ ways, so $(2^k-1)^n$ possible answer sets.

The widely accepted meaning of "multiple choice question" really only allows one of the $k$ answers to be selected, so there are $k^n$ ways to answer a paper with $n$ MCQs.

Comment: @BStar An MRQ may have only one correct answer.